# How to correct db access error for Hyperledger Explorer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am installing Hyperledger explorer and I have an access error -

> error when connecting to db: { error: password authentication failed
>   for user "hppoc"
>       at Connection.parseE (/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554
>   :11)
>       at Connection.parseMessage (/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.
>   js:379:19)
>       at Socket. (/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:11
>   9:22)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
>       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)   name: 'error',   length:
>   101,   severity: 'FATAL',   code: '28P01',   detail: undefined,
>   hint: undefined,   position: undefined,   internalPosition: undefined,
>   internalQuery: undefined,   where: undefined,   schema: undefined,
>   table: undefined,   column: undefined,   dataType: undefined,
>   constraint: undefined,   file: 'auth.c',   line: '328',   routine:
>   'auth_failed' }

I took all the defaults using the supplied json files. Has anyone ideas how this could be corrected? I am running the standard sh file with the distribution (below) -

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#Redirecting console.log to log file.
#Please visit ./logs/app to view the application logs and visit the ./logs/db to view the Database logs and visit the ./log/console for the
 console.log
# Log rotating for every 7 days.

rm -rf /tmp/fabric-client-kvs_peerOrg*

mkdir -p ./logs/app & mkdir -p ./logs/db & mkdir -p ./logs/console

LOG_CONSOLE_PATH="logs/console/console-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log"

echo "************************************************************************************"
echo "**************************** Hyperledger Explorer **********************************"
echo "************************************************************************************"
echo "***** Please check the log [$LOG_CONSOLE_PATH] for any error *****"
echo "************************************************************************************"

export DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST=true
node main.js name - hyperledger-explorer >>$LOG_CONSOLE_PATH 2>&1 &

find ./logs/app -mtime +7 -type f -delete & find ./logs/db -mtime +7 -type f -delete & find ./logs/console -mtime +7 -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

To bring up explorer , we need to install db . we have createdb.sh script.Try to create the db , and if we need to mention any username and pass, change those parameters in .json file.And try to restart.If you face any issue, let me know.:)